# U-boot make march error

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot

After following the instructions here, http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot, for setting up U-Boot, I am getting the following error when running the command `make -j8 -s`

> cc1: error: bad value (armv5) for -march= switch
>
> Makefile:912: recipe for target 'u-boot.cfg' failed

I have searched around on google, but I have not been able to find much about this. Any suggestions to what the problem is or what I am missed/am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply came as the CROSS_COMPILE variable was not set...

Comment: can you be more verbose so this answer can also help the others?

Answer (score 0):

As the linked guide notes, you must first

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=the-prefix-of-the-arm-cross-toolchain-installed-
```

and then run make because as you're building (most likely) software for another architecture 'gcc' will not accept the various flags that we pass in when building.